# Server Administration specific Configuration in TeamCity gets lost after refresh

Tags: testing, automated-tests, teamcity, neoload

I'd like to integrate [NeoLoad](https://www.neotys.com/neoload/overview) tests into TeamCity. Therefore I've installed the corresponding NeoLoad Plugin and now I need to add a "NTS Configuration" to provide the mandatory license parameters for running the tests.
The NTS Configuration has to be added at "Administration"->"Neotys Team Server".

[image]

I provide following required information: "URL", "Login User", "Login Password" and the label.

[image]

After saving it, the NTS Configuration is visible as a newly added entry BUT after switching to another page or after a refresh- the entry disappears. I've never experienced such a behaviour in TeamCity. I don't know whether it's about TeamCity or the NeoLoad Plugin.

I'm using "TeamCity Enterprise 10.0.5 build 42677" and NeoLoad 5.2.1.

Any guesses?
Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: P.S.: the log of TeamCity did not provide us any hint...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved. It seems that there is *no* compatibility between TeamCity Version 10.0.5 and the NeoLoad Plugin 1.0.5.

For verification, I've installed the latest TeamCity version (2017.2.3) and integrated the NeoLoad Plugin (Version 1.0.5) and it works.

This question can be closed.